# Ruby: parse csv data to pdf

Tags: ruby, csv, pdf-generation, prawn

I am using prawn gem to generate pdf document

how one can parse data from csv to pdf

i have used the code some thing like this

```
Prawn::Document.generate("user.pdf", :page_layout => :landscape) do
  exa_url = "D:/userReport.csv"
  csv_data = open(exa_url).read.lines.to_a
  headers = CSV.parse(csv_data[6]).first
  body = CSV.parse(csv_data[7..-1].join)
  table body, :headers => headers, :font_size =>10, :position=>:centere
end
```

it me gives an error,

Is there any other approach, or other advice to fix this

Comment: Please include the actual error messages you get...

Comment: undefined method `pos' for nil:NilClass   this is the error i got

Comment: What's the backtrace? What line in your code is giving that error? Please help us help you.

Comment: headers = CSV.parse(csv_data[6]).first  , this line throws the error

Comment: can you post the whole backtrace,edit it into in the question, The file names and all that stuff is important if you want people to consider helping you.

Answer (score 1):

`headers = CSV.parse(csv_data[6]).first` doesn't mention `pos`, but your error message does. So you are looking at some error inside CSV.parse (I guess).

Most likely your csv_data Array doesn't contain what you think it does or is otherwise invalid.

In other words, it sounds like you're dealing solely with an issue of parsing CSV data. Try reducing your code to a simpler case and investigate your CSV data.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an issue with opening your CSV file. I'd recommend doing some irb detective work and making sure `csv_data = open(exa_url).read.lines.to_a` is working. Sounds like you're trying to interact with csv_data and it's nil.